# Qt 5.6 cannot be built with VS2015 under Win7?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, qt5.6

According to [this page](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-5.6.0-tools-and-versions), Qt 5.6 with VS2015 is only supported under Windows 10! (I suppose `-` means "not supported" and `X` means "supported").

Is it really the case? No way it can be built under Windows 7.....

I'd like to upgrade my compiler to VS2015, and take this oportunity to also upgrade all my 3rd party libraries (including Qt)....but I really can't upgrade my windows version (company policy).

Anyone tried to build the beta under Windows7? Did it work well?

Comment: Interesting. I see no reason why wouldn't it build. It uses MSVC libraries, not the OS. Well, of course it uses some OS libraries too, but those uses shouldn't really depend on the compiler. Looks to me that they just meant to say that binaries are only provided for Windows 10.

Comment: That's a possibility, it's true that you can either compile it yourself or download the binary. But even, I would be surprised that win10 binaries would not work for win7...

Comment: Well, with all those manifests and other version stuff it could be possible. Or maybe they just meant to say that they didn't test them for Windows 7. Either way, it's really weird because one would expect it to support any version supported by VS 2015 itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded Qt5.6 beta from [here](http://download.qt.io/development_releases/qt/5.6/), installed VS 2015 on a Windows 7 64 bits machine.

I successfully compiled Qt and could execute a hello world. Windows7 may not be officially supported, but it works well.